# What are the odds that a path between two nodes passes through a specified subset of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let G be a connected graph, and let S be a specified, randomly selected,  subset of the nodes of the graph (say 5%). Let  a and b be two randomly selected nodes from the graph.  What is the probability that the shortest path between a and b passes thought at least one node from S?

I know the answer to this question is surely contingent on a number of factors I’m not including in this description. Anyone interested in aiding me in answering this question can just states the hypothesis he needs (small world etc.).

Comment: You might at least say more about the kind of hypotheses you are interested in. Otherwise, a valid answer is "If $G$ is $K_n$, the probability is $0$." Another subtlety is that the shortest path might not be unique; what is the answer if there are several shortest $a,b$-paths, and some of them pass through $S$ but others don't?

Comment: It's a connected graph. I really don't have any other specific hypotheses.